# Does the saving in Core Data is done in the main thread?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Do you save Core Data entities in the main thread or create a new thread with a block?

Comment: First google result for [core data thread](http://www.google.com/search?q=core+data+thread): [Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html)

Comment: SO the answer is yes then.

Comment: Lol, I didn't think it was a yes/no question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData only saves a context. You can have multiple contexts at once on multiple threads and contexts cannot be shared between threads. Also entity objects exist (are created/fetched/updated) in 1 context (and cannot be shared between contexts).

So: a context needs to be saved in thread where it is created and used. If you created it in the main thread you need to save it in the main thread. If you created it in a background thread, you need to save it in the background thread.